# Electric potential of dipole at equitorial plane

Tags: electrostatics, potential

The electric potential at equatorial plane of a dipole is $0$. Then it does not require any work for moving a test charge from infinity to that point.

I think work done is zero. If this is true then will a free charge will sit there (in the equatorial plane)?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: If traverse a mountain slope at constant altitude, I do no work. If I slip--then I certainly do not just sit there.

Comment: What made you think the potential at the equatorial plane of a dipole is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate the potential function you will find that the gradient of the potential at the equatorial plane is NOT zero, so the force is not zero.  Charges can only sit at minimums of potential energy; a zero potential might not be a minimum (or maximum).

The reason no work is done by the field (or by you) as you move the charge is that the force is perpendicular to the direction of motion. 
$$dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$  If every $d\vec{r}$ is in the equatorial plane, no work is done, but you must still hold the charge in the plane because the force is non-zero (no local extremum at the equator). If you release the charge from rest it will accelerate along a line of force.